# Comparing numerical results between mathematical operations performed with two different languages

Tags: python, precision, numerical-methods, idl-programming-language

I'm currently trying to port an algorithm from IDL to Python 3 and while comparing results I came across the following questioning: How do I look at the numbers and determine if I'm effectively reproducing the results?

Assuming that different languages will deal slightly differently with pointing float precision it is expected that the results should be a bit different but up to which point this is acceptable?

In the figure below I will use the mean values of the data sets produced by IDL and python to illustrate my point:

[image: Mean values of the respective arrays]

While in some of the calculations I can see that the values are similar in others they don't quite hit the mark.

Looking at the step below where a trace of the set of matrices that will be used to is used to determine if there are points where the solution is ill posed I had the following results for both IDL and Python:

[image: Trace]

Which looks quite good (may I say that?).

The (100, y-dimension, x-dimension) matrices where this trace was calculated from are then re-organised to calculate a least square fitting that is ultimately where the values that will create the means will arise.

I'm using those comparisons to find clues on what need to be changed and improved on the python version therefore I appreciate any thoughts that can lead me in this direction.

In advance I thank for your time.

Comment: I'd say this is not possible unless you define the standard of "being sufficiently alike." Also the two figures have different colour scales, so it's difficult to say whether they look alike.

Comment: "up to which point this is acceptable" I'd say that is up to you. You can check relative errors and decide if the values are high enough to affect your experiment. The differences are most likely related to minor implementation differences, such as the order in a sequence of additions, etc. Some of it you may control, but some probably not (e.g. how to do matrix multiplication if you are using NumPy).

Comment: I think your results show substantial relative differences, and my guess is there's an implementation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each number representation injects into the computation process two quantities:
- some **value** ( the primary quantity represented by the number )
- some **error** ( the secondary quantity, as a side-effect, caused by a numerical representation )

No one can compute without the former ( The Value ... )

No one can escape from the latter, being in practice visible as (i-)responsibility for the computation-process flow's  final result error ( better accumulated levels of uncertainty ).

There are not much strategies for coping with principal errors ( uncertainties ) embedded in simplified "common" representations, as advocated by IEEE-754(-1985).

### Yet,
there are many fields of science,
where numerical methods with such soon degraded result precision
do not suffice . . . So?

Be it astronomy, be it interplanetary flight dynamics calculations, there are cases, where IEEE-754 numbers soon fail to provide an acceptable service.

Here the computing tools provide a few solutions to chose from.

```
>>> import decimal
>>> 
>>> with decimal.localcontext() as locCTX:
...      for aPREC in range( 20, 31 ):
...          locCTX.prec = aPREC
...          ( pure_dec_LSQ_5DoF( locCTX, dec_fmin_x0_SEARCH_TRIM_TO_BE_PRECISE, decX, decY ), pure_dec_RESi( locCTX, dec_fmin_x0_SEARCH_TRIM_TO_BE_PRECISE, decX, decY ) )
...
(Decimal('0.038471115298826195147'),           (Decimal('0.023589050081780503'),           Decimal('-0.082605913918299990'),           Decimal('0.150647690402532134'),           Decimal('-0.091630826566012630')))
(Decimal('0.0384711152988261953165'),          (Decimal('0.0235890500817804889'),          Decimal('-0.0826059139182999933'),          Decimal('0.1506476904025321349'),          Decimal('-0.0916308265660126301')))
(Decimal('0.03847111529882619531420'),         (Decimal('0.02358905008178048823'),         Decimal('-0.08260591391829999331'),         Decimal('0.15064769040253213501'),         Decimal('-0.09163082656601263007')))
(Decimal('0.038471115298826195324048'),        (Decimal('0.023589050081780488368'),        Decimal('-0.082605913918299993309'),        Decimal('0.150647690402532135021'),        Decimal('-0.091630826566012630071')))
(Decimal('0.0384711152988261953231489'),       (Decimal('0.0235890500817804883582'),       Decimal('-0.0826059139182999933087'),       Decimal('0.1506476904025321350199'),       Decimal('-0.0916308265660126300707')))
(Decimal('0.03847111529882619532322276'),      (Decimal('0.02358905008178048835950'),      Decimal('-0.08260591391829999330863'),      Decimal('0.15064769040253213501998'),      Decimal('-0.09163082656601263007070')))
(Decimal('0.038471115298826195323213788'),     (Decimal('0.023589050081780488359358'),     Decimal('-0.082605913918299993308625'),     Decimal('0.150647690402532135019974'),     Decimal('-0.091630826566012630070702')))
(Decimal('0.0384711152988261953232136753'),    (Decimal('0.0235890500817804883593541'),    Decimal('-0.0826059139182999933086251'),    Decimal('0.1506476904025321350199740'),    Decimal('-0.0916308265660126300707023')))
(Decimal('0.03847111529882619532321367314'),   (Decimal('0.02358905008178048835935336'),   Decimal('-0.08260591391829999330862505'),   Decimal('0.15064769040253213501997413'),   Decimal('-0.09163082656601263007070231')))
(Decimal('0.038471115298826195323213665675'),  (Decimal('0.023589050081780488359353229'),  Decimal('-0.082605913918299993308625043'),  Decimal('0.150647690402532135019974132'),  Decimal('-0.091630826566012630070702306')))
(Decimal('0.0384711152988261953232136649869'), (Decimal('0.0235890500817804883593532187'), Decimal('-0.0826059139182999933086250437'), Decimal('0.1506476904025321350199741307'), Decimal('-0.0916308265660126300707023064')))
```

Python is happy to enjoy it's ***almost***-**infinite precision mathematics**, so the simplest step forwards is to re-design the algorithm on the python side, so that is contains purely this sort of *almost*-non-degrading precision mathematics and you suddenly stand on the safer-side, independently of where the IDL original was or not.

Given one re-formulated all computation steps in this precision non-degrading way, the results are worth the time:

```
def pure_dec_LSQ_5DoF(   decCTX,                                                Xopt,                                                decX_measured,                            decY_measured ):                            # [PERF] ~ 2400 [us] @ .prec =   14
    return decCTX.add(   decCTX.add( decCTX.power( decCTX.subtract( decCTX.fma( Xopt[0], decCTX.power( Xopt[4], decCTX.fma( Xopt[1], decX_measured[0], Xopt[2] ) ), Xopt[3] ), decY_measured[0] ), decimal.Decimal( 2 ) ), #        ~ 2800 [us] @ .prec =   28
                                     decCTX.power( decCTX.subtract( decCTX.fma( Xopt[0], decCTX.power( Xopt[4], decCTX.fma( Xopt[1], decX_measured[1], Xopt[2] ) ), Xopt[3] ), decY_measured[1] ), decimal.Decimal( 2 ) )  #        ~ 7700 [us] @ .prec =  100
                                     ),
                         """                                                        [0]                    [4]                  [1]                        [2]          [3]        _measured[i] ~ [X1,Y1], ...
                                                                                     |                      |                    |                          |            |                                  
                                                                                     |                      |                    |                          |            |         Xopt[0,1,2,3,4] ~ [a,b,c,d,f]
                                                                                     |                      |                    |                          |            |                            | | | | |
                                                                                     +----------------------|--------------------|--------------------------|------------|----------------------------+ | | | |
                                                                                                            |                    +--------------------------|------------|------------------------------+ | | |
                                                                                                            |                                               +------------|--------------------------------+ | |
                                                                                                            |                                                            +----------------------------------+ |
                                                                                                            +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                         """                                                                                                                                                                                    
                         decCTX.add( decCTX.power( decCTX.subtract( decCTX.fma( Xopt[0], decCTX.power( Xopt[4], decCTX.fma( Xopt[1], decX_measured[2], Xopt[2] ) ), Xopt[3] ), decY_measured[2] ), decimal.Decimal( 2 ) ), #        ~ 1340 [ms] @ .prec = 1000
                                     decCTX.power( decCTX.subtract( decCTX.fma( Xopt[0], decCTX.power( Xopt[4], decCTX.fma( Xopt[1], decX_measured[3], Xopt[2] ) ), Xopt[3] ), decY_measured[3] ), decimal.Decimal( 2 ) )  #
                                     )
                         )
```

If one needs `~ 14`-digits precision, just spend `~ 2.4 [ms]` per such step,
if one needs `~ 28`-digits precision, just spend `~ 2.8 [ms]` per such step,
if one needs `~100`-digits precision, just spend `~ 7.7 [ms]` per such step,
if one needs `1000`-digits precision, just spend `~ 1.3 [ s]` per such step,
not bad at all,
is it?

```
# [PERF] ~ 2400 [us] @ .prec =   14
#        ~ 2800 [us] @ .prec =   28
#        ~ 7700 [us] @ .prec =  100
#        ~ 1340 [ms] @ .prec = 1000
```

And that's all already included in python tools and cool to re-use, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The real question is not if different implementations give you similar values, which might give you a feeling that they are right.

The real question is if the values are meaningful at all !

Comment: The two-watch problem: "A man with a watch knows what time it is. A man with two watches is never sure."

Comment: @njuffa: a watch is rarely on time. A stopped watch is bang on time twice a day !

Comment: I guess the equivalent to a stopped watch is the answer "42"?

Comment: @njuffa: yep, 42/42, 563/563